# How does electric charge work?

Tags: electricity, electrons

Electrons specify the material but if they flow between the atoms, that would change the material of the atoms right? And that would change the conductivity and some other stuff. I'm confused someone please explain.

Answer (score 2):

Well it's not electrons that specify a material. It's actually the nucleus. Atomic number which is the signature of an atom is the number of protons inside the materials. So to change a material you need to add/remove protons (which happens in nuclear reactions like decay or fusion). 
The change of electron position(and by this I mean adding/removing electrons) can at best give you a charged system. It's like you're juggling with different number of balls at different times but it's still you who's juggling the ball. 
The properties like conductivity are classically defined by the motion of electrons, like how much it collides while moving and all that. It won't change the composition of the material. It's like if you're juggling the balls while sitting, or standing or walking. It affects the way(speed) with which you juggle, but it's still you juggling!